# Downloading links from a txt file

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I want to do a simple exercise where I want to download a bunch of links from a txt file. The files are all annual reports in txt format too. I also want to preserve the name of each link as the file name with '/' replaced with '_'. I have tried the following so far. I do not know how to open a txt file with URLs in each line, which is why I am using a list of URLs. But I want to do it properly. I know that the following code is no way near what I want but I just wanted to give it a try. Can anyone please help with this. Thanks a million!

```
    import requests

urllist = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/100240/0000950144-94-000787.txt",
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/100240/0000950144-94-000787.txt",
]

for url in urllist:
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using:

```
import requests

urllist = ["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/100240/0000950144-94-000787.txt",
           "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/100240/0000950144-94-000787.txt" ] # links are the same

for url in urllist:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        fn = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_") # on windows, : is not allowed on filenames
        with open(fn, 'w') as file:
            file.write(r.text)
```

---

Output:

```
https___www.sec.gov_Archives_edgar_data_100240_0000950144-94-000787.txt
```

Only one file was generated because links are repeated

Answer (score 0):

If your links are in a file lets say urls.txt where each link in a different line that you can use this:

```
import urllib.request
with open('urls.txt') as f:
    for url in f:
        url = url.replace('\n', '')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , url .replace('/', '_').replace(':', '_'))
```